# How to work with iAds using xcode 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iad

Presently I am Working With Integrate iAds and make a lite version of the app. My Problem is Previously I am working with iAds is xcode 4.1.3 but Presently I was used xcode 3.1.3 iAds are not supporting what we do please help me.

```
 NSString *contentSize = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
```

This line error: `ADBannerContentSizeidentifier320x50'undeclared(first use in this function)`

Answer (score 3):

First, even in the newest versions of iOS, `ADBannerContentSizeidentifier320x50` is no longer the preferred constant. Use [`ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009562) instead.

But I think the real issue here is that Xcode 3.1.3 is too old to include the iAd framework. It was first included in iOS4 and so won't be there in anything older. Your choices therefore are:

- Use a newer version of Xcode (and iOS)
- Don't use iAds. There are other ad networks such as AdMob that still support older devices

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your SDK to the latest version.

You need at least iOS 4.0 if you want to use iAd. And I think Xcode 3.1.3 only includes the iPhone OS 3.0 SDK.

Time to upgrade to Snow Leopard?

Comment: My TL ask him  Integrate iAd and make a lite version of the app
please help me