# How to implement the iAds in xcode 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, iad, iadstsuserex

In iPhone Programmer presently I am working with iAds in xcode 3.1.3 but in my Project this kind of errors are occurred. please tell me it is possible to work in iAds in xcode 3.1.3?
My error is

```
ADBannerView.h:88: error: expected ')' before 'ADBannerView'
             ADBannerView.h:97: error: expected ')' before 'ADBannerView'
            ADBannerView.h:102: error: expected ')' before 'ADBannerView'
            ADBannerView.h:110: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_4_0_DEP__IPHONE_4_2'
             ADBannerView.h:111: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_4_0_DEP__IPHONE_4_2'
             ADBannerView.h:112: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_4_2'
             ADBannerView.h:113: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_4_2'
    /Users/girishramdas/Desktop/iAds sample/iAdSuite/BasicAdBanner/Classes/TextViewController.h:59: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'ADBannerView'
```

Comment: You can refer to my answer over here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927209/how-to-work-with-iads-using-x-code-3-1-3/6927247#6927247

Thanx.....

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have error handeling for if an ad cannot be displayed. If you dont have this it may cause a crash like this.

something like:

```
    - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
        if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
             /* set banner not visible here
        }
```

Comment: thank you this is use full for me

Comment: thank q it is very use full to me but x code 3.1.3 is supporting ids are not what is the best way please suggest me.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to ask. And I was reading up and I dont think the iAd framework is supported in Xcode3.

Comment: You'll either need to upgrade to Xcode4 or use another ad network such as AdMob.

Comment: thank you BlueMeanie i will follow your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This one has explained the step by step [implementation of iAds...](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app)